# For positive $a$ and $b$, and for $u\in[0,1]$, can we solve for $v$ in $a>b\sqrt{1-v^2}+\sqrt{1-(u+v)^2}$?

Tags: inequality

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive numbers and $u \in [0, 1]$.
Can we solve this inequality for $v$?
$$
a > b \sqrt{1-v^2}+ \sqrt{1-(u+v)^2}
$$
I need the points for $v$ in the interval $[-1, 1-u]$ for which the corresponding equality holds, together with the information on which side of a point the inequality holds.

When I enter the corresponding equality in Mathematica, I get a ridiculously large formula. Any ideas on how to do this manually?

Context: I'm trying to expand [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3241466/42723) of mine. And I think solving this can help me.

Comment: A friend just told be how to do this, squaring twice, the second time move the square root to one side.

Comment: Then you have a fourth degree polynomial